# Closing the Fancybox Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

There is a button when you click on which the fancybox with the form opens, after filling out the form and clicking on the send button, I want this window to close automatically and another one opens with the text "that the message was sent successfully" and after a couple of seconds it would disappear, or when pressed outside the window area.

```
$("form").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php", //Change
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        $('#alert-massage').fadeIn(500);
        alert("Thank you!");
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Done Functions
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
});

<div id="modal">
<div class="modal__wrap">
    <div class="modal__title">
        Write me
    </div>
    <form >
        <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
        <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="kylun-Serg">
        <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="kylun1serg@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="popup-form">
        <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Name"   required>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name = "E-mail"required>
        <input type="phone" placeholder="Phone" name = "Phone">
        <textarea placeholder="Massage" name="Massage"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">
        Send
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue? What did you try?

Comment: @Anurag Srivastava I don’t know how to do it on jqvery) I can instead of alert display a block with the desired message, but then I don’t know how to make it close after clicking the send button, and another block with a message opens

Comment: Look into `Bootstrap`, there are components in it for your specific needs

Comment: @Anurag Srivastava I try not to use Bootstrap

Comment: Without showing some coding attempt I'm afraid you will not get much help. Try to browse through plenty of online resources, you will surely come across an example to suit your needs. Stackoverflow is for helping you out when you're stuck.

Comment: Did you check the docs - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when submitting form you can trigger a function

```
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn">Send</button>
```

and function will do hide the modal and display success message and reload the current page.

```
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "none";
alert('Form submitted successfuly.');
location.reload();
}
```